# Scripting an unattended Firefox setup in Windows

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

I work in a training environment where the Firefox set is *ancient*, and they refuse to create a new image. So I end up wasting a lot of time setting up by updating to the latest Firefox, removing useless addons, and installing more useful ones from files. I also tweak some of the options.

Is there a way to automate the above using a batch file? I need to do the following:

- Update to a recent Firefox. I am happy to include a downloaded installer.
- Remove usless addons. The environment is cloned, so the profile is all the same.
- Install new addons, either from downloaded files or remotely.
- Import some settings.

Comment: How far back are we talking? I can't remember when Firefox introduced auto-updating, so it could be as simple as a few clicks, followed by just copying profiles over perhaps?

Comment: @SimonSheehan Version 25. I think it came out in the 1930s. I can update it using the Help Menu, but ti’s so old I need to do it twice — first to version 43, and then again to the current version. For a room full of machines. At the start of every new class.

Comment: Would using [Mozilla Firefox Portable Edition](http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/firefox_portable) be an option?

Comment: @user3169 I hadn’t thought of that. I need to give it a try in a couple of days. I would still prefer to update the one already installed, but the Portable version is certainly an option. I also wonder whether I can simply replace the profile folder for the addons … ?

Comment: Haven't tried it, but I would think you can replace the default 'portable' profile folder with your existing current FF version one. Either rename the folder or in profiles.ini edit the file name in the path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here’s how I do it. I have downloaded a standalone installer andrun a batch file to do the following:

- Remove the old profile folder
- Copy a standard profile folder in its place
- Run the standalone installer

I was pleasantly surprised when it all worked. The standard profile folder already has the appropriate addons installed and the old ones removed, and, for good measure a clear history and cache.

Thanks